# /bin /etc /lib64 /root /sbin deleted or moved by mv folder/* /* while su

Tags: shell, centos

OS is Centos 6.5 64-bit

I downloaded a tar file and wanted to untar and `mv` it.

I untared, then accidentally (as root) ran `mv folder/* /*` instead of `mv folder/* .` bash said it couldn't overwrite some files, then asked permission for others. I ctrl-c'd out.

I've left terminal session open, but have exited `su`.

Now I've lost access to most `shell` commands, can't `ls` any directories and can't get back to `su`.

The webserver and services still seem to be running. I can run very few commands, `cd` is one of them and when I try to `cd` to `/etc` or `/bin` it errors with `no directory found`.

*EDIT* Just noticed all folders missing from `/` (`bin`,`etc`,`lib64`,`root`,`sbin`) got moved to `/var` directory, I tried `/var/bin/su` & get: 
`-bash: /var/bin/su: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can't you run `/var/bin/su` directly?

Comment: @Darkhogg `/var/bin/su: user root does not exist` I think we determined it can't be done because /etc is at /var/etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*IMPORTANT*
If you're here, and have ran `mv` incorrectly, can't run `shell` commands, and folders missing from root directory (`/`), first of all, if you have `SU`, DO NOT exit `SU` until fixed, because you won't get it back. If you are remotely connected, if you disconnect, you will not be able to `ssh`, leave server alone, don't `reboot` - most running services should be OK. You can attempt one of the many solutions suggested by Patrick...however you'll likely need physical access if you screwed up like I did.

Once in front of the machine, I rebooted it. As expected, I did receive a kernel panic.

I thought this would be a pretty easy fix, insert livecd, enter rescue mode UP TO THIS POINT IT WAS EASY - then I had to try and mount my root directory. However I needed more than just a simple mount command.

This was because I, like many people, had an lvm file system, and this was the first time I've had to deal with a rescue like this. I had to search the web to see what I needed to do. I've consolidated that information to this post. Here was my process to fix my issue.

1)Inserted Centos_6.4_min cd

2)GUI interface asked what I wanted to do, chose Rescue

3)Rescue tried to mount current system, but indicated I had no Linux partitions

4)Chose to enter `shell` when option was given

At this point I tried many things to get system mounted, with no luck, I'm pretty sure these are all the steps I had to take (because of lvm):

5)Scanned my volumes,

`lvmdiskscan`

6)Ran lvscan, showed all listed as "inactive"

`lvscan`

7)load device module

`modprobe dm-mod`

8)change the volumes that exist to active

`vgchange -ay`

9)Ran `lvscan` again, now all items listed as "active"

10)Created mountpoint & mounted the logical partition

`mkdir /mnt/root`

`mount /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /mnt/root`

11)Moved folders back (YOU may need others):

`mv /var/{bin,etc,lib64,mnt,root,sbin} /`

12)`reboot`

13) SUCCESS!

Answer (score 25):

If your system has `busybox` installed, you can use this to put things back.

`busybox` is a binary with lots of standard utilities built into it. Things such as `mv`, `sh`, `ls`, etc.

From your comment on Pavel's answer, it sounds like everything ended up in `/var`. You can try doing `/var/bin/busybox mv /var/{bin,etc,lib32,lib64,root,sbin,usr} /`. That should get most of your system operational again. There are a few directories such as `/tmp` which also exist as `/var/tmp`, so you can't just move them. Hopefully those are the ones that `mv` complained about and they were left alone.

### Getting a root shell

You also mentioned that you lost your root shell, and that `su` is giving you a `ld-linux` library error. You might be able to use the following:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib64 /var/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /var/bin/su
```

*Note: Upon attempting this, it does not work. This is because `su` requires several files in `/etc` (`passwd`, `pam.d`, and others). If `/etc` were still intact, this would have a good chance of succeeding.*

### Without busybox

If you do not have busybox available, you might be able to use the same ld-linux trick as for `su`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib64 /var/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /var/bin/mv /var/{bin,etc,lib32,lib64,root,sbin,usr} /
```

### From a live CD

As discussed in the comments, if you've lost the root shell, you're pretty much stuck. Basically in order to fix this you need root privileges. The only way to get there is to have a utility such as `su` or `sudo` escalate your permissions (both of which are non-functional at this point), or hijack another program already running as root (depending on what's running, not likely possible).

This leaves the only option being a live CD. Once booted into a live CD (or live USB, or whatever), just mount the root volume, and move the affected directories out of `/var` back to their original home in `/`.

---

## Synopsis of what happened

`folder/*` would have expanded out to something such as `folder/foo` and `folder/bar`.
`/*` would have expanded out to something like `/bin` `/lib32` `/lib64` `/etc` `/home` `/root` `/var`. Noting that `/var` is the last item.
So when the shell expanded out all those globs, it would have run something like this:

```
mv folder/foo folder/bar /bin /lib32 /lib64 /etc /home /root /var
```

As `/var` is the last item in the list, everything got moved into it.

---

## Why `/var/bin/su` errors with `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory`

Almost all binaries in linux are dynamically linked against `ld-linux`. `ld-linux` is the library responsible for loading the other libraries needed by a binary. On your system this lives at `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Since this directory got moved, any dynamically linked executable will no longer work.

The reason busybox works is that busybox is statically linked. It does not use `ld-linux`.

Comment: Good idea. CentOS typically has a busybox installed because of *initramfs*, so that might work well.

Comment: `busybox` sounds like the perfect solution, unfortunately not installed, will after this is fixed...in the meantime, is there anyway to correct path for commands to execute `/var/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` instead of `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`? This seems to be what is killing the commands in `/var/bin`

Comment: @Patrick: Could you please add the information that also the command OP intended to use is wrong? I could then delete my answer as it's now (almost) redundant. Is it the right way to use stack exchange, by the way?

Comment: @user1296209: Are you sure you don't have busybox installed? I thought it's necessary for initramfs and therefore installed by default to CentOS.

Comment: @user1296209 I added 2 sections, **without busybox** and **getting a root shell**.

Comment: I feel like we're close, can't move files in the way mentioned because of `permissions`, and: `/var/bin/su: user root does not exist`

Comment: It's looking for several things in `/etc` which aren't there (`/etc/passwd`, `/etc/nsswitch`, `/etc/pam.d`, and probably more). For `su` to work, `/etc` must be back in it's original location. Unless you've got a root shell laying around, I think you're stuck :-(

Comment: well there is a lot of good stuff in your answers, and I appreciate it all, guess I'll have to do a livecd on monday, from there what would be the quickest fix for this?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda You do not need to delete yours. It is still perfectly relevant. Multiple answers covering different aspects is what stack exchange is good for :-)

Comment: @user1296209 Once you get a livecd up, just mount the root volume and move those directories back. That should be all you need to get running again.

Comment: @Patrick: What if one is clearly superior and the other one becomes obsolete?

Comment: @Patrick another possibility...or is it possible to change permissions in current state?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda That's perfectly fine too. Your answer still has good information in it :-). If you want, lets continue the discussion in the chat. Comments aren't a good place for it.

Comment: @user1296209 no. Unless you can run `su`, `sudo`, or hijack some other program which is already running as root, you're stuck.

Comment: And I'm guessing I'm stating the obvious here, but the server probably won't boot if restarted, correct?

Comment: @user1296209 correct. You'll likely get a `kernel panic - could not find init` (exact wording will vary, going from memory).

Comment: and for future reference, if it at all matters, /usr did not get moved

Comment: @Patrick, great analysis and synopsis. But `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be ignored by setuid programs, since not to do so would be a huge security hole. (Anyway it's a moot point since `/etc/passwd` etc. must be present as well.) Recovery boot from a CD is the only way out.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda I started with a Centos 6.4 min base dvd, then `HowtoForge` recommendations for a Centos 6.4/Nginx/ISPConfig setup. I don't recall installing, or any documentation mentioning `busybox` previously...here is what I attempted to run busybox (as instructed by Patrick) : `[user@web1 /]$ cd /var/bin`
`[user@web1 bin]$ busybox`
`-bash: busybox: command not found`
`[user@web1 bin]$ /var/bin/busybox`
`-bash: /var/bin/busybox: No such file or directory`
`[user@web1 bin]$`
Please let me know if it might be hiding elsewhere, google search didn't help, and I don't have grep or find available

Comment: I can now `ls`:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib64 /var/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /var/bin/ls`

Answer (score 10):

`mv folder/* ./*` is wrong as well. You should be more careful about the semantics of the commands you run. The `mv` command with more than two arguments just takes all argument except the last one and moves the paths they point to into the directory specified in the last argument.

To move all directories (except hidden ones) from *folder* to the current directory, you should use:

```
mv folder/* .
```

You have broken your running system. Your shell and builtin commands continue to work. You will have to boot a live CD and move the directories back. I'm not aware of a bash builtin to move/rename files that would allow you to fix the situation without rebooting, see Patrick's answer for more details.

Comment: I didn't realize that:
I can cd to /var/bin & /var/etc, looks like folders got moved to var, anyway I can move them back?...without livecd?

Comment: I tried /var/bin/su & get: 
-bash: /var/bin/su: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Aha... I'll fix up the answer.

Comment: what should my `mv` command have been to move all files and folders from folder to current directory?

Comment: Booting a live system is certainly a good idea, but with a bit of luck, he can repair his system by just moving the files back (at least on my system, mv does not allow to replace non-empty directories, nor does it allow to replace symlinks with directories. So only those directories either previously either not present of empty in `/var` should have been moved from `/`. So unless he did overwrite some file directly in `/var` (but at least on my system, there are only subdirectories and symlinks in `/var`), he probably can fix everything by just moving the moved directories back to root.

Comment: @celtschk: Please read the answer from Patrick and you'll see that it's not as easy as you think.

Comment: @user1296209: `for file in folder/; do mv $file .; done`

Comment: @celtschk without root access..from what I've gathered, it can't be done

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: The problems in his post are all about the problems to fix it *in the very same system that was borked.* When booting a live system, all those problems are gone because the `mv` commands you issue are the live system's `mv` command.

Comment: @celtschk: What you're talking about has been already discussed in depth under Patrick's answer.

Comment: @user1296209: If you boot a live system, you certainly have root access on your life system. Your actual system is just a mounted partition with no special meaning for the live system. The only complication is that your `/` and `/var` directories may be on different partitions, in which case you have to mount both.

Comment: @celtschk: I updated the second part of the answer that comes from the time before I knew what exactly happened to the files. I neglected to fix it because all the discussions went under Patrick's answer. It should be ok now.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: I don't see where he even mentions a live system to boot into. His post (besides the explanation what happened) is all concerned about why the system doesn't work as expected and how one might get things working *on the very same system that just got borked.* Not from a live system.

Comment: @celtschk: Is the current version acceptable, as an answer containing complementary information regarding the (in)correctness of the original command?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: Well, your `mv` command certainly is right (I don't know whay I was thinking you'd need `for` in my comment above), but you mention it *before* mentioning a live CD. And on the borked system, you'll have to go through the trouble Patrick described to get it running. From the live CD, you'll just have to mount the corresponding partition(s) and can then issue `mv` normally. Which was my point.

Comment: @celtschk: The discussion about how `mv` command should have been originally used is not much related to a discussion about fixing the system. Therefore it doesn't matter if it's mentioned before or after it.

Comment: Err, you're right. Sorry, I got confused.

Comment: @celtschk: No problem.

Comment: I see. Feel free to edit the answer if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I accidently moved /usr to /usr_old and everything went to hell. Luckily I stayed in the prompt and was able to execute the following command to restore the usr folder:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr_old/lib64 /usr_old/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr_old/bin/mv /usr_old /usr
```

Comment: Welcomme to U&L, was that the only command you type ? Please provide a more detailed procedure. (specially for a ten mont old question, there is no need to hurry)

Comment: Yes after I typed that command everything was restored. Maybe I should mention that I was root during all this.